# How can I create Wireshark variables to represent an IP Address?

Tags: networking, wireshark, pcap

When analyzing network traffic in Wireshark, it would be helpful on occasion to look at a string variable representing an IP address instead of the actual IPv4/6 address.

In the IP source or destination column, instead of seeing 192.168.1.44, I would like to see "tom's laptop" or "smtp-server". Is this possible? Some type of IP-to-String aliasing?

I understand there is an option to enable name resolution for the Network Layer, this would translate a public IP into its registered domain name. Specifically when dealing with private IP addresses, this would not be helpful.

Comment: To accomplish this, I added a custom IP address/domain name mapping in my %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts on Windows 7. This is where Wireshark will look first if configured to use an External name resolver for the Network Layer. 

Contents of **%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts**

    127.0.0.1   localhost
    ::1         localhost
    192.168.1.64 iPhone
    
Now, 192.168.1.64 would now be displayed as iPhone in the appropriate Wireshark IP column.